# Find the value of pi

Tags: python

i need to find the value of pi using below pattern, 
pi = 4/1-4/3+4/5-4/7+4/9
i have been able to find the denominator and change the sign but i am having trouble using it in the while loop, can someone please take a look at it can guide me. thank you

```
def pi(error):
    prev = 1
    current = 4
    i = 1 
    while current - prev > error:
        d = 2.0* i +1
        sign = (-1)**i
        current = current + sign * 4 / d 
        i = i +1
    return current
```

my console froze when i run this on my python.

Comment: with which error value? Please make sure that the error can be reproduced.

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot to update `prev`, so the loop never terminates. I also put in an `abs` in case the difference is negative.

```
def pi(error):
    prev = 1
    current = 4
    i = 1
    while abs(current - prev) > error:
        d = 2.0* i +1
        sign = (-1)**i
        prev = current
        current = current + sign * 4 / d
        i = i +1
    return current
```

I tried `pi(0.001)` with this code and got the answer `3.1420924036835256`. Note that if you try something like `pi(0.000000001)` the console will freeze for a while because it will take a long time for the loop to terminate.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the mistake.And also one more thing i am not getting the expected value can you tell me where i am doing the math wrong. pi(0.01) should give me 3.1611986129870506 but i am getting different value.( 3.146567747182955)

Comment: @jojo Why should it give `3.16...`?

Comment: thank you for the quick response. This is one of the hw and for the example thats the value it is printing. 
for p(0.01) it should give 3.1611986129870506 and for pi(0.0000001) it should give me 3.1415928535897395. once again i really appreciate your help.

Comment: I can only assume you've been given an algorithm which has a different termination condition from the one your program uses. I don't think I can help unless you give me the exact instructions you were given.

Comment: Echoing @Paul_Boddington, the 2 values either side of 3.1611986129870506 are 3.121594652591011 and  3.12236366153074. neither of which are < 0.01 away

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could use `itertools`:

```
itertools.count(1, 2)    # generates the sequence 1, 3, 5, 7, ...
itertools.cycle([1, -1]) # generates the sequence 1, -1, 1, -1, ...
```

So you could do, and this generates the right values (note: moved the 4* outside of the loop to get the correct answers):

```
from itertools import count, cycle #, izip - if Py2
def pi(error):
    p = 0
    for sign, d in zip(cycle([1,-1]), count(1, 2)):  # izip for Py2
        n = sign/d
        p += n
        if abs(n) < error:
            break
    return 4*p

>>> pi(0.01)
3.1611986129870506
>>> pi(0.0000001)
3.1415928535897395
```

Or using a generator:

```
from itertools import count, cycle, takewhile #, izip - if Py2
def pi_series():
    for sign, d in zip(cycle([1,-1]), count(1, 2)):  # izip - if Py2
        yield sign/d

def pi(error):
    return 4*sum(takewhile(lambda x: abs(x) > error, pi_series()))
```

But this doesn't add the last term (need `takeuntil`)

Comment: Great answers! I'm just learning python so this really helps. You are missing a `return` in the second one.