# calculation of pi, getting different value than book

Tags: python, series, pi

> The mathematical constant π (pi) is an irrational number with value approximately 3.1415928... The precise value of π is equal to the following infinite sum: π = 4/1 - 4/3 + 4/5 - 4/7 + 4/9 - 4/11 + ... We can get a good approximation of π by computing the sum of the first few terms. Write a function approxPi() that takes as a parameter a floating point value error and approximates the constant π within error by computing the above sum, term by term, until the absolute value of the difference between the current sum and the previous sum (with one fewer terms) is no greater than error. Once the function finds that the difference is less than error, it should return the new sum. Please note that this function should not use any functions or constants from the math module. You are supposed to use the described algorithm to approximate π, not use the built-in value in Python.

I have done the below program but for some reason I am getting the different value from the one in book.

```
def pi(error):
    prev = 1
    current = 4
    i = 1
    while abs(current - prev) > error:
        d = 2.0* i +1
        sign = (-1)**i
        prev = current
        current = current + sign * 4 / d
        i = i +1
    return current

output In [2]: pi(0.01)
Out[2]: 3.146567747182955
```

But instead I need to get this value

```
>>> approxPi(0.01)
3.1611986129870506
>>> approxPi(0.0000001)
3.1415928535897395
```

Comment: As I posted in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069677/find-the-value-of-pi, I can  not see how the `error=0.01` returns 3.1611..., the 2 values either side of 3.1611986129870506 are 3.121594652591011 and 3.12236366153074. neither of which are < 0.01 away

Comment: Because (as @skyking wrote) the McLaurin expansion of arctan(x) evaluated at x=pi/4 is an alternating sum, hence converges slowly. You can convert it to a positive-only formula by pairing terms, but it will still converge slowly. Read about any of the other faster-converging sums.

Answer (score 3):

The approximation you're using is very poor at converging, that is you have to loop quite a lot of times to get a reasonable value. You see that the difference will be 1/d and that's the accuracy. You'll have to loop 5000 times to get four digits 50k times to get next and 500k to get next and so on (that is exponential time complexity for the digits).

This could be one of the reasons that you see a discrepancy here, that you simply get the situation where rounding errors add up. Since you need to use that many iterations you will never get near the full precision of the floats you're using. Another source of discrepancy is that your reference probably is using another exit condition, with your condition you should get an error less than the provided (ideally), and you've got it (3.146567747182955-pi < 0.01). It actually looks like your reference is using the condition `abs(current-prev) > 4*error` instead.

The formula you're using is that pi=4arctan(1) and using McLaurin expansion of arctan(x) for a value of x that is on the limit of converging at all. To get better performance one should use lower x in that expansion. For example pi=16arctan(1/5)-4arctan(1/239) could be used (this gives linear time complexity for the digits):

```
def pi(error):
    a = 1.0/5
    b = 1.0/239

    prev = 1
    current = 0.0
    i = 0
    while abs(current - prev) > error:
        d = 2.0* i +1
        sign = (-1)**i
        prev = current
        current = current + sign * (16*a - 4*b)/d
        a = a*1.0/(5*5)
        b = b*1.0/(239*239) 
        i = i +1
    return current
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the stopping rule for your function and approxPi are different. In fact, your estimation is better. If you print out all the values of current, you will see that when i equals 50 your function produces your desired output. But, it goes beyond that and produce a better approximation.

Answer (score 0):

So to get the answer you are looking for then the question as posed is wrong in how it describes the exit condition.
Re-organizing you get Pi = 4*(1/1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + ...), to get 3.1611986129870506 with an error of 0.01, then you looking at the subsequent terms and stopping when the term < error:

```
from itertools import count, cycle  #, izip for Py2
def approxPi(error):
    p = 0
    for sign, d in zip(cycle([1,-1]), count(1, 2)):  # izip for Py2
        n = sign / d
        p += n
        if abs(n) < error:
            break
    return 4*p
```

Then you get the correct answers:

```
>>> approxPi(0.01)
3.1611986129870506
>>> approxPi(0.0000001)
3.1415928535897395
```

Using your code (from @PaulBoddington: [Find the value of pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069677/find-the-value-of-pi))

```
def pi(error):
    prev = 0
    current = 1
    i = 1
    while abs(current - prev) > error:
        d = 2.0*i + 1
        sign = (-1)**i
        prev = current
        current = current + sign / d
        i += 1
    return 4*current
```

Note: This is not the difference between the current sum and the previous sum, so the question is wrong, but it is equal to `difference_between_sums < error*4`. So to get the correct exit for your original code just multiply the error by 4, e.g.:

```
>>> pi(0.04)
3.1611986129870506
```